# Error Cannot Implicity convert type 'System.IO.Stream' to 'Project_Jynx.Stream'

Tags: c#

I keep on getting this error:

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.IO.Stream' to 'Project_Jynx.Stream'  C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project jynx W.I.P EXPLOIT\Project_Jynx\Project_Jynx\Form1.cs 27  Project_Jynx.

I need help on fixing this because i want to finish this coding.

[image]

Comment: Please post the code instead of a screenshot

Comment: It seems like there is a class named `Stream` in your namespace that clashed with `System.IO.Stream`. Could it be the case?

Comment: It's too long to add the code...

Comment: You can also write `var stream = openFileDialog.OpenFile();\n if (stream == null)` instead

Comment: var stream = openFileDialog.OpenFile();\n if (stream == null) gave me even more errors!

Comment: @JoePlaysTv You shouldn't add the code in a comment but in your question. Click on "edit" to edit your original question to include your source code.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, you have a `Stream` class defined in your project. The compiler does not know that you actually meant `System.IO.Stream`. It thought you meant the `Stream` in your project when it saw this line:

```
Stream stream;
```

And then you assign `openFileDialog.OpenFile()`, which returns a `System.IO.Stream`, to it.

To tell the compiler to use `System.IO.Stream`, just write `System.IO.` in front:

```
System.IO.Stream stream;
```

Comment: While this solved the problem i posted, i'm getting 2 more errors!:Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'Project_Jynx.Form1.Using(Project_Jynx.Stream)' has some invalid arguments C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project jynx W.I.P EXPLOIT\Project_Jynx\Project_Jynx\Form1.cs 13 Project_Jynx and i'm getting:Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.IO.Stream' to 'Project_Jynx.Stream' C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project jynx W.I.P EXPLOIT\Project_Jynx\Project_Jynx\Form1.cs 20 Project_Jynx

Comment: @JoePlaysTv Make your `Using` method accept a `System.IO.Stream`, and every other occurrence of `Stream` that you actually mean `System.IO.Stream`. Also, why do you have a `Stream` class in your class anyway? Consider deleting that class if it is not used.

Answer (score 0):

I started an answer, but Sweeper beat me to it. So here's a different one: don't use a `Stream` at all:

```
if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    try
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog.FileName);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = $"Error reading file {openFileDialog.FileName}: {e}";
    }    
}
```